# Opera will not play BBC audio stream

Tags: audio, opera

I am running Opera One(version: 106.0.4998.16) on Manjaro and I cannot get BBC Sounds (e.g. [Radio 3](https://www.bbc.co.uk/sounds/play/live:bbc_radio_three) to play. I get the error

> This content doesn't seem to be working

I can play the BBC stream on Chrome, and I can play other sounds (e.g. Youtube) through Opera

I have  looked at the [Opera forum](https://forums.opera.com/topic/50281/bbc-sounds-app-won-t-play-radio-programmes) which seems to be referring to *libffmpeg.so* which is installed and up to date

I have tried turning off ad blocker and tracker blocker, but still get same problem